# How do I search a text file for a string and then print/return/put out what line of the file it was found on as a number in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

So, I want to use the number I get from it in this:

```
line = answer to question 
database.read.lines[line]
```

Database being the text file I am searching in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
query = gets.chomp
database.each_line.with_index do |line, index|
  if line.include?(query)
    puts "Line #{index}: #{line}" 
  end
end
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `line.include(text)` instead of `line.include?(line)` ? I guess a small typo there.

Comment: Ok, but how do I put the number I get into put into `database.read.lines[]` something like that? in order to print out the whole line the text was found on

Comment: Also, how do I then use a gets statement (I think thats what it would be called, a statement) to allow the user to input a string that it would search for and output the line number that it is on

Comment: @EPICBRONY I update my answer in a min. you can comment if it is what you require or not : )

Comment: @spickermann Thanks, that is what I needed, but one more thing, how do I get it to puts the line after the line that the query was found in I.E. `File: Line 1: Hello Line 2: Hi Query: Hello What is printed/putsed out: Hi`

Comment: @spickermann Thanks, I have edited your code to fit my needs, and thus it is the answer I was looking for `if File.read(file).include?(query) == true
 file.each_line.with_index do |line, index|
  if line.include?(query)
   puts IO.readlines("file.txt")[index + 1]
  end
 end`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way :

```
text_to_find = 'some random text' # use gets method to take input from user
text_found_at_index = database.readlines.index{|line| not line[text].nil? }
```

Hope, this is what you require : )